# Safari doesn't display jQuery .html loaded content

Tags: jquery, html, mobile-safari

I want to display a content of an external page into a div using .html,
my code works fine in other browsers except Safari:
You can check the page here :
http://portal5b.hotsplots.com/test.php

my html code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="second_module">
</div>
<script>
    $("#second_module")
        .html('<object data="tv.php" width="100%" height="100%"/>');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I see nothing in iPhone Safari.

Comment: was a mistake sorry

Comment: have you looked at using an iframe? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: the code works in other OS and others browsers

Comment: Could it be just a browser cache issue?!

Comment: I emptied and sill not working

Answer (score 0):

try with ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#second_module")
        .html('<object data="tv.php" width="100%" height="100%"/>');
});
```

Also note that

```
<head>
```

tag is not closed in your code.

Comment: How that? OP is obviously setting script after element is already available in DOM...

Comment: @user2997418 have you zoom the page and checked? I hv checked this with different URL it works for me.